# Database becomes empty with no rows when running it on android device

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Hello I have a wierd problem when I run my application on the emulator it works fine and displays all the company names from the database in a list view , but when I run it on a real device the database gets empty with no rows .(cursor.getCount()returns 0 ) .. I don't know why is this happening !? Thanks in advance

my logcat :

```
06-15 18:56:23.031: D/dalvikvm(9213): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 77K, 3% free 12870K/13191K, paused 30ms
06-15 18:56:23.066: D/dalvikvm(9213): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 109K, 4% free 12954K/13447K, paused 26ms
06-15 18:56:23.066: I/dalvikvm-heap(9213): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.093MB for 262160-byte allocation
06-15 18:56:23.086: D/dalvikvm(9213): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 13210K/13767K, paused 13ms
06-15 18:56:23.106: D/dalvikvm(9213): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 13210K/13767K, paused 17ms
06-15 18:56:23.106: I/dalvikvm-heap(9213): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.537MB for 465140-byte allocation
06-15 18:56:23.126: D/dalvikvm(9213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 5% free 13664K/14279K, paused 1ms+1ms
06-15 18:56:23.161: D/dalvikvm(9213): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 7% free 13409K/14279K, paused 13ms
06-15 18:56:23.161: I/dalvikvm-heap(9213): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.743MB for 476816-byte allocation
06-15 18:56:23.181: D/dalvikvm(9213): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 13875K/14791K, paused 1ms+1ms
06-15 18:56:23.261: D/dalvikvm(9213): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 7% free 13875K/14791K, paused 32ms
06-15 18:56:23.261: I/dalvikvm-heap(9213): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.550MB for 846420-byte allocation
06-15 18:56:23.286: D/dalvikvm(9213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 14702K/15623K, paused 2ms+1ms
06-15 18:56:23.616: D/CLIPBOARD(9213): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-15 18:56:36.801: E/yallaaaaaaaaaaaa(9213): 0
06-15 18:56:36.801: I/System.out(9213): count0
```

Comment: what does the logcat say?

Comment: what is your scenario in details?

Comment: @22kar I just posted now my logcat

Comment: @Tarek I created a database and inserted in it using sqlite browser name of some companies and I want to display these companies in a listview and that worked with me when I tried to run the app on the emulator , but when I tried to test it on a real device the activity was blank and the count of results from the select query is 0  which means that the database is empty on the mobile just having tables with no row values

Comment: maybe the reason is that inserting rows in this way works only on rooted phones and not in a non-rooted phone. Fortunately the emulator is rooted.

Comment: just write some code to add some rows programmatically, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I wrote an insertion code and the problem persists so I am rooting now my device . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

well sometime ago i too faced a similar problem..

create a temporary table say temp and insert rows into it from another table.

```
public void populate_temp() 
{

dbsqlite.execSQL("delete from temp");
dbsqlite.execSQL(" insert into temp(name) select city from City ORDER BY city ASC ");

}
```

then populate a list by retrieveing values from the temporary table

```
public List<String> getAllLabels() 
{
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "select DISTINCT name from temp";
    dbsqlite = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbsqlite.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
             labels.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    dbsqlite.close();

    return labels;
}
```

this may not be a good programming practice but works just fine! ;)